# Compare column value with nested select

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need to find, for example, a user by his posts `id`. Database with users and posts may look like this:

```
Users:

 id | username | password
 ---+----------+---------
   1|      John|     ****
   2|       Eve|     ****
   3|      Rich|     ****

Posts:

 id | author_id | contents
 ---+-----------+---------
   1|          1| I'm John
   2|          2|  I'm Eve
   3|          3| I'm Rich
   4|          3| It's Rich not rich, keep that on mind...
```

My situation is just slightly different from post<->user situation, because in my case, I don't need any information about post.
So according to the above, and with help of some random posts I found (with MySql problems I never know what to search on google) I thought my query should look like this:

```
SELECT username, id 
FROM `user` 
WHERE id IN (SELECT author_id FROM `post` WHERE author=$MYID)
```

This does not work, so I guess more magic than mysterious `IN` statement will be needed.

Comment: `$MYID` is a post id, isn't it? So your inner condition should be `WHERE id = $MYID`.

Comment: Yeah, I happened it to confuse it. Unfortunatelly I'm so unsure with using MySQL that I created SO post before double-checking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem `post` versus `posts` and `user` versus `users`?

```
SELECT username, id
FROM `users`
WHERE id IN (SELECT author_id FROM `posts` WHERE author=$MYID);
```

More importantly, though, earlier versions of MySQL (up to 5.6.x) do a poor job of opitimizing `in` queries.  You can rewrite this as:

```
SELECT username, id
FROM `users` u
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM `posts` p WHERE author=$MYID and p.author_id = u.id)
```

Comment: Problem was the fact that I searched `author_id = $MYID` instead of searching for the `id`. However I'm glad for your note about performance, I'll try that query instead. `\`users\` u` stands for `\`users\` AS u`? Is that some shorthand?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this may work:

```
SELECT username, id FROM `user` WHERE id IN (SELECT author_id FROM `post` WHERE id=$MYID)
```

Comment: Oh... Can't believe I did such a stupid mistake. At least, I've also rewritten it to my SO example.